# converting String into long in java

Tags: java

I couldn't convert a `String s="45,333"` into number like long or double. Can anyone help me to solve the issue.. i have added the model snippet, when i try to run that code it showing `NumberFormatException`..

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
long a=85200;
NumberFormat numberFormat=NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
String s=numberFormat.format(a);
Long l=Long.parseLong(s.toString());
System.out.println("The value:"+s);
System.out.println("The value of long:"+l);
}
```

Comment: Which is the value of s? AFAIK, parseLong expects a number without thousands separators.

Comment: What exception did it raised?

Comment: String s=numberFormat.format(a);long a=85200;

Comment: Use the same `NumberFormat` to `parse` the number. You are mixing locale-sensitive formatting with hardcoded parsing.

Answer (score 14):

Consider `NumberFormat.parse()` method instead of `Long.parseLong()`.

`Long.parseLong()` expects `String` without any formatting symbols inside.

Comment: Very true, he is getting exception because ',' is getting added between the numbers

Answer (score 3):

Mixing `NumberFormat` and `Long.parseLong()` isn't a good idea.

`NumberFormat` can be locale-aware (in your example it uses the default locale for your computer) or you can explicitly specify format patterns, whereas the `parseXXX()` methods of `Number` subclasses only read "plain" numbers (optional minus sign+digits).

If you formatted it with `NumberFormat`, you should use `NumberFormat.parse()` to parse it back. However you shouldn't depend on the default locale, try to specify one instead (or use `DecimalFormat` with a pattern). Otherwise you're likely to encounter some nasty and hard to detect bugs.

If you don't care about the format, consider using `Long.toString()` to convert a long value into string and `Long.parseLong()` to convert it back. It's easier to use, thread safe (unlike `NumberFormat`) and works the same everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out you can use `NumberFormat.parse()` like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long a=85200;
    NumberFormat numberFormat=NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    String s=numberFormat.format(a);
    Long l;
    try {
        l = numberFormat.parse(s.toString()).longValue();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        l = 0L;
        // Handle exception
    }
    System.out.println("The value:"+s);
    System.out.println("The value of long:"+l);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
long l = Long.valueOf(s);
System.out.println("The value of long:"+l);
```